# C# GetMethod vs GetRuntimeMethod

Tags: c#, reflection

I am using `GetRuntimeMethod` to get a method out of type. Everything works fine but I have noticed that there is a `GetMethod`. What is the difference between the two?

```
this.target.GetType().GetRuntimeMethod(
    "MethodName",
    new System.Type[0]
)?.Invoke(targetObject, null);
```

From the names I can only guess that `GetRuntimeMethod` works while the program is running. And `GetMethod` works during program compilation?

Are there any advantages of using one instead of another? (This last question can be deductible from the answer to what is the difference between the two of course)

Comment: "_And GetMethod works during program compilation?_" How can a method work during program compilation? Wouldn't that require the compiler to actually execute the code? ;-)

Comment: With regard to why there are two seemingly equivalent methods, look at the "Applies To" section in the documentation for both methods. Now, why the designers/architects of the respective platform version choose to provide or not provide certain methods, well, i unfortunately have no insight and could only offer wild, blind, and quite likely misguided and false speculation about that topic :-(

Comment: @elgonzo That is why I called it "a guess". For example, compiler could recognize that this is compile time method and get reference to the method during compilation time and optimize this call. While `System.Reflection` `GetRuntimeMethod` could get the method during runtime. And `GetMethod` would be just an imitation of `runtime` reflection.

Comment: `GetRuntimeMethod` only works on a `RuntimeType` otherwise throws an exception. `GetMethod` works on `SystemType`, the abstract base class for `RuntimeType`. `GetRuntimeMethod` calls `GetMethod` after validating the type is actually a `RuntimeType` (what else could it be?), so it is slower than `GetMethod`.

Comment: This paragraph from the documentation also seems relevant: "`Type` is an abstract base class that allows multiple implementations. The system will always provide the derived class `RuntimeType`. In reflection, all classes beginning with the word Runtime are created only once per object in the system and support comparison operations." And [this](https://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/02/when-is-a-type-not-a-type.html)

Comment: @NetMage Thank you, that is super useful. Feel free to answer this question, since there are no other answers and your comments answer my question with enough details for me - I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GetMethod works on `System.Type`, the abstract base class for `RuntimeType`. `GetRuntimeMethod` calls `GetMethod` after validating the type is actually a `RuntimeType` (and not a (possibly user defined) child of `Type`), so it is slower than `GetMethod`. `GetRuntimeMethod` throws an exception if not passed a class derived from `RuntimeType`.

From the [documentation for `Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> `Type` is an abstract base class that allows multiple implementations.
>   The system will always provide the derived class `RuntimeType`. In
>   reflection, all classes beginning with the word Runtime are created
>   only once per object in the system and support comparison operations.

Also [this article](https://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/02/when-is-a-type-not-a-type.html) has further details on extending `Type` and when you might need a `RuntimeType` specifically.